# Find the orbit and stabilazer of the action $\mathcal D_8\times \{1,2,3,4\}\longrightarrow \{1,2,3,4\}$.

Tags: group-theory, permutations

The action is $\mathcal D_8\times \{1,2,3,4\}\longrightarrow \{1,2,3,4\}$ defined by $\sigma \cdot x=\sigma (x)$ where $\mathcal D_8$ is the diedral group of order $8$. I identify $\mathcal D_8$ to the subgroup of $\mathfrak S_4$ $$\{id,(1234),(1432),(13),(24),(12)(34),(23)(14),(13)(24)\}.$$

I thing the action is transitive, and thus $\mathcal O_1=\{1,2,3,4\}$, and the stabilizer of $1$ is $$G_1=\{id,(24)\}.$$
Now, I'm trying to compute $$\mathcal D_8/G_1$$
but I have problem to do it. I did as:
$$(1234)=(12)(23)(34)=(12)(234)$$ and thus $[(1234)]=[(234)]$.
$$(1432)=(2143)=(21)(14)(43)=(21)(143)$$
and thus $[(1432)]=[(143)]$. We also have $$[(13)]=[(13)],\quad [(24)]=[(24)],\quad [(12)(34)]=[(34)]...$$
but I have to be wrong since $$|\mathcal D_8/G_1|=4.$$
So how can I do ?

Comment: $G_1 = \{1,(2,4)\}$ ?

Comment: of course, thanks.

Comment: What's the meaning of   [(1234)]=[(234)] ?

Comment: @2000: It's of course the class of $(234)$ in $G/G_x$ !